# How to get image value from Django form?

Tags: django-forms, bootstrap-4

```
 <div class="card-text">
     <img id="image_upload_preview" {% if adminform.form.photo.? %}src="{{ adminform.form.photo.? }}"{% endif %} />
     <input type='file' id="inputFile" name="photo" class="img-choose" />
  </div>
```

how to get value of image in the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="card-text">
    <img id="image_upload_preview" {% if adminform.form.photo.value %}src="{{ adminform.form.photo.value }}"{% endif %} />
    <input type='file' id="inputFile" name="photo" class="img-choose" />
</div>
```